# How do I remove this distance in the toolbar?

Tags: padding, android-toolbar, appbar

I did not use the code from any padding or margin.but This distance there is.How can I remove This distance?
.........................................................................

[image]

This is my code >

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_white_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_50"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<include layout="@layout/content_news" />
```

Answer (score 0):

update below line which is you wrote in ImageView tag.

use

```
 android:layout_gravity="end"
```

instead of

```
 android:layout_gravity="start"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the line.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```